# Chef: reading attribute value from shell environment variables

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to read value of an environment variable in attributes file of chef cookbook. Many posts have described that i can use ENV[] of ruby to achieve what i want.

My attributes file looks something like this

```
default['some_object']['some_attribute'] = ENV['SOME_ENV_VAR']
```

While running recipe, it seems to result in empty string. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume that what you describe is the right way to do so (which is not), note that you need to set the environment variable on the node where you execute `chef-client`.

`chef-client` execution, has several phases:

- **compilation phase:** all recipes are loaded in the order specified by the expanded run-list.
- **convergence phase:** Each resource is executed in the order identified by the run-list, and then by the order in which each resource is listed in each recipe. ...each action configures a specific part of the system.

for more information about chef-client about the phase, see [chef-client overview](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html).

the evaluation of your environment variable, namely `ENV['SOME_ENV_VAR']` happens on the compilation phase. what you should really do, is to use [json attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908735/1184717):

> you can provide custom attributes by including [`--json-attributes`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options) (i strongly advise you to visit the documentation, since it holds examples) in chef-client
>
> `-j PATH, --json-attributes PATH`
> The path to a file that contains JSON data. Used to setup the first client run. For all the future runs with option -i the attributes are expected to be persisted in the chef-server.

you can always use the environment variables that are set for you to construct a json structure and then feed it to chef-client when you execute it.

Comment: some other process is already setting env-var for me, for this reason i want to use this approach. what is wrong if I do it this way?