# How to use ruby_block variables, out side of ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

I have a code, in that code it contains ruby_block. What are the values generating in that `ruby_block`, I want use them in out side/in another resource in same recipe file.

```
Dir.chdir("#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}")
Dir.glob("test-*.msi").each { |file| File.delete(file)}

windows_zipfile "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}" do
source node['seps_infrastructure']['zip_file']
action :unzip
overwrite true
end

ruby_block 'check_vpn_ip_list' do
block do
node.run_state['msi_file'] = Dir.glob(""test-*.msi"")
node.run_state['ver'] = (node.run_state['msi_file'])[0].split('-    ')[3].chomp(".msi")
end
end
puts  node.run_state['ver']
puts  node.run_state['msi_file']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable inside a Chef recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551104/using-a-variable-inside-a-chef-recipe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703978/108654 - here you can find how you can use variables in ruby_block.

Answer (score 0):

first, as a rule of thumb, i would advise you to utilize chef resources and not have ruby code outside of such resources (since ruby block outside of chef resource will be executed on [compilation phase and not the convergence phase of chef-client run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55089728/1184717). of course, there are some exceptions to this rule). for instance, place

```rb
Dir.chdir("#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}")
Dir.glob("test-*.msi").each { |file| File.delete(file)}
```

within a `ruby_block` resource.

relating to your question, you can assign a node attribute within the `ruby_block` and use the same node attribute when needed. for instance:

```rb
ruby_block 'foo' do
  block do
    node.default['files'] = Dir.glob("test-*.msi")
  end
end

execute 'baz' do
  command "echo #{node['files']}"
end
```

Comment: Not on any other resource.